# iPhone + UITableView + row height

Tags: iphone, uitableview, height, row

I am setting the row height of my `UITableView` using following code

```
[tableView setRowHeight: 100.00];
```

I am using the single line as separator in the `UITableView`.

Eventhough setting the height above, height of row does not get change.

Comment: It matters WHEN you set row height

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

delegate method. and return 100.0 there.

Comment: Careful. Pratik didn't say he wanted per-row height. heightForRowAtIndexPath can be expensive with a lot of rows.

Comment: This is the right though expensive answer: There is one thing that I do not understand. Why the hell Apple insist on knkowing the RowHeight? Why not just ask the Row Height from (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and get the height from that?

Comment: if all the cells have the same row height, setting rowHeight is much more efficient than using this delegate method.

Answer (score 23):

You should avoid the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` if all your rows are of similar height and use the `rowHeight` property. According to the documentation:

> There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of rowHeight. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

In the UITableViewController subclass it could be done, for instance, in the `viewDidAppear` method (the `UITableViewController` has a reference to the tableView):

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 79.f;
```

Answer (score 7):

The row height is baked into the cells when they are first displayed.

Did you set UITableView#rowHeight before setting the data source?
If not, do so.
If for whatever reason you can't, your other option is to call UITableView#reloadData after setting the row height.

Comment: This solved it for me. Setting rowHeight *before* I set the data source totally fixed the problem. reloading the data did as well. Thanks emp.

Answer (score 3):

I did like this, here `tableobj` is nothing but `UITableView` object in my application.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [tableObj setRowHeight:100.0f];
}
```

Or  handle it in `numberOfRowsInSection:` like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [tableObj setRowHeight:100.0f];
    return [soandso count]; // soandso is my object
}
```

Because set the `rowHeight` before setting the data source. It worked for me (for equal row heights).

Answer (score 0):

The better and cleaner solution is to implement the delegate function (Maybe not the best one if your UITableView has many rows ...).

Also, think that UITableVieCell are UIView so you could change their height firstly...

Delegates are very powerful in iPhone dev, here the UITableViewDelage:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You can also change the indentForRow, displayCellForRow, heightForRow,edit stuff .....

Answer (score -6):

I dont think there is such a method in UITableView...

Instead you can use the property rowHeight...
Try, 
tableView.rowHeight =100;

Comment: Actually it's in UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: properties are just easier ways to access Getters/Setters.  doing tableView.rowHeight = 100, is exactly the same as [tableView setRowHeight:100].

getters/setters are automatically created when u synthesize properties.