# UITableView cell's height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I have a simple question, not able to sort it out. I have a `UITableView` in my application. There are 3 section and each section has 3 rows.

I want to increase the height of first cell of the first section. I am using the delegate for this but it increases the height of the first cell of the third section.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && sectionValue==0) 
    {         
        sectionValue=1;
        return 180.0;        
    }
    else
    {
        return 44.0;        
    }   
}
```

Comment: sectionValue is set 0 in viewdidload.

Comment: You must check `indexPath.section == 0` too! (+ votedown because this question asked more than ten times!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone + UITableView + row height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635783/iphone-uitableview-row-height)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different height for alternative cell in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3529246/), [Manage height of UITableView cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122814/manage-height-of-uitableview-cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `indexPath.section` -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section==0) 
    {  
        return 180.0;

    }
    else
    {
        return 44.0;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this......

```
 indexPath.section
```